# AWS: ACM was unable to renew the certificate automatically because of the following error: PCA_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: amazon-web-services

I received a message from AWS warning of a  certificate to expire. It contained this phrase:

```
ACM was unable to renew the certificate automatically because of the following error: PCA_ACCESS_DENIED.
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Private Certificate Authority and select **Actions|Configure CA Permissions**. Ensure **Authorize ACM access to renew certificates requested by this account.** is checked.

using the AWS CLI (cloudshell) run the following:

aws acm-pca list-permissions --certificate-authority-arn "arn:aws:acm-pca:us-east-2:ACCOUNTNUMBER:certificate-authority/xxxxxxx-b0e1-446e-a2ec-6f6c466e4684"

If you get back:

```
{
    "Permissions": []
}
```

This indicates the CA is not authorized to renew the cert.

Your permissions should resemble:

```
{
    "Permissions": [
        {
            "CertificateAuthorityArn": "arn:aws:acm-pca:us-east-2: ACCOUNTNUMBER:certificate-authority/xxxxxxx-b0e1-446e-a2ec-6f6c466e4684",
            "CreatedAt": "2022-07-15T16:21:51.890000+00:00",
            "Principal": "acm.amazonaws.com",
            "SourceAccount": "ACCOUNTNUMBER",
            "Actions": [
                "GetCertificate",
                "IssueCertificate",
                "ListPermissions"
            ],
            "Policy": "{\"Version\":\"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\":[{\"Sid\":\"1\",\"Effect\":\"Allow\",\"Principal\":{\"Service\":\"acm.amazonaws.com\"},\"Action\":[\"acm-pca:GetCertificate\",\"acm-pca:IssueCertificate\",\"acm-pca:ListPermissions\"],\"Resource\":\"arn:aws:acm-pca:us-east-2:ACCOUNTNUMBER:certificate-authority/xxxxxxx-b0e1-446e-a2ec-6f6c466e4684\",\"Condition\":{\"StringEquals\":{\"aws:SourceAccount\":\"ACCOUNTNUMBER\"}}}]}"
        }
    ]
}
```